# Invalid index ,on crystal reports for loop

Tags: c++, .net, for-loop, crystal-reports

I am have a problem using my for loop with crystal reports fields.

With my for i am trying to extract all the SQLExpressionFieldDefinition's from my report .
In order to do that , i am geting the count of the SQLExpressionFieldDefinition in the report.

The for loop works perfect until it reaches it last iteration.Then it trows Invalid index.
In other words SQLExpressionFieldDefinition->Count  = 5 for exemple , the first 4 iteration work ,when it reaches the 5th the invalid index problem appears.

Here is the code :

```
for ( nIterator = 1; nIterator <= rpt->DataDefinition->SQLExpressionFields->Count; nIterator++ )
            {
                SQLExpressionFieldDefinition 
                    *sqlExpressionFieldDefinition = rpt->DataDefinition->SQLExpressionFields->get_Item(nIterator);

                strText = sqlExpressionFieldDefinition->Text;}
```

Waiting for your answers.Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about crystal reports..normally array indexes start from 0 and run up to n-1. So accessing value at count will be invalid index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexers for arrays should start at value 0, not at 1, and end at value `Count - 1`.
Crystal Reports is no exception to this rule.

```
for (nIterator=0; nIterator < rpt->DataDefinition->SQLExpressionFields->Count; nIterator++ )
```

Comment: That is how i initially thought to .It trows the invalid index when it go's for the 3th time , to check if nIterator is <= whit count .

Comment: That's seems very strange unless you try to remove items from the SQLExpressionFields array while looping over it. If you have initially a Count of 5 items they should be there while you loop over them using an index that goes from 0 to 4.